# Distribution of $\frac{X_{1}}{X_{1}^{2}+X_{2}^{2}}$, where $(X_1,X_2)$ is bivariate normal?

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution

What is the distribution of $\frac{X_{1}}{X_{1}^{2}+X_{2}^{2}}$ when $(X_1,X_2)$ has a bivariate normal distribution?

Comment: You can't divide in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Do you mean $X=(X_1,X_2)$ is bivariate normal? Then are $X_1$ and $X_1$ independent or correlated?

Comment: Please add self study tag.

Comment: I believe that this question has been asked and answered before on stats.SE, but don't have a specific question to point to.

Comment: Related (but not the same question): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/641559/distribution-of-angle-of-two-dimensional-normal-vector